# Eclipse ADT running out of memory and keeps crashing?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory

I've been using ADT for a while now and things have been going smoothly enough. All of a sudden, Eclipse declares that it's short on memory "Java heap space" troubles and whatnot... I've searched all over and every piece of advice seems to point to editing the file `eclipse.ini`.

Most of the advice said to turn the memory up to `512m`. I did that, but it wasn't fixing anything. So I upped it to `1024m`. Still no luck, so I upped it again to `2048m`. Still no success! My `eclipse.ini` now looks like this:

```
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

ADT still crashes. It seems like `2048m` should be plenty of memory already, but ADT still complains about it. So is there another problem that could be prompting this symptom? Keep in mind that my app was working just fine minutes before the IDE started going bonkers.

**EDIT:**

I've also tried deleting the entire ADT folder from Applications (I use a Mac), re-placed it back with a different copy of the ADT again. This also did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the culprit: an errant JAR file in the project library. After deleting it, things ran normally again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem. I solved it by making space in my c drive.
**You can try this:**

1. Run Ccleaner and make some space in your C drive
2. Create your AVD with 512 memory

Comment: No luck. :\ I have around 95 GB of free space on the hard drive and it's not making any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Back up your dev environment

Install latest version of eclipse with adt into a new folder.  https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

When you start the new version of eclipse point it to your old workspace.

Edit 
One of things I do is set every project to the same api level.  Api 19.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm already using the latest version of Eclipse ADT. :\

Comment: Just added something that might help